# PHPenv install not working?

Tags: php

I am trying to test [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv).
I have cloned the repo and set the paths, but when I try to perform

```
$ phpenv install php-5.3.20
```

I just get a

```
phpenv v0.0.4-dev
$
```

Shouldn't this command add an entry under the ~/.phpenv/versions ?

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is an old post, but I was having the same problem now, and I solved it by installing [php-build](https://github.com/php-build/php-build#use-with-phpenv) (check *Use with phpenv*) and then running `phpenv install 5.5.21`. Then I got errors for missing dependencies, so I installed the below and reran the installation

> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential libxml2 libxml2-dev 
> sudo apt-get build-dep php5-cli
> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libmcrypt-dev libreadline-dev
> phpenv install 5.5.21
> ```

but now 45 mins after the `phpenv install`, it's still stuck on `[Compiling]: /tmp/php-build/source/5.5.21`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to checkout to *master* branch if you currently are in *dev*. It helped me.

Additional information you can find here: https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv/issues/19